# Unable to store json response in a variable. Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

link_to causes the json response to be downloaded to my machine which I dont want. I want to be able to store the response in a variable. How can this be done?

Thanks in advance.
Vishal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using `link_to` with the `:remote` option set to `true` you may just be linking to a bit of JavaScript, not actually retrieving it with AJAX.